# Is there a way to fetch Spark cluster mode logs to the Airflow SparkSubmitOperator task logs?

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, hadoop-yarn

I have multiple SparkSubmitOperators launched in Cluster mode.
Currently, I have to use "yarn logs" command to fetch the logs manually.

Ideally, I would like to have the logs fetched in the Airflow task logs directly. I could not find a satisfying solution... any help appreciated